# Php login page; redirect after logging in by number to user page

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, numbers

I want to have php page, where you input a six-digit number into textbox and you press button. After that it will redirect you to "/*that number you put in*.html". I had something like this before, but I can't remember how to do that.

Thanks for answers

Comment: any code you have tried?

Comment: oh. would you like the source code in a zip folder? this is rich

Comment: Just try to write and post your code.

Comment: I had this file, and my friend was trying to change all website to php, but made mess in it. This is what left

Comment: <?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/objednavky/{$username}.html";

<?php


?>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <label for="username">Číslo zásilky:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Zobrazit informace">
        </form>

Comment: It was before looking first for file, so that's why there is "$filename", but I don't probably need that.

Comment: edit your post to contain code, not in comments. This being php and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["sixdigit"])){
    header('Location: '. "URL/".$_GET["sixdigit"]);
}


?>


<form>
  6-digits<br>
  <input type="text" name="sixdigit">

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's great! But, I need to redirect to html. When I tried to add .html to header, it didn't work... Sorry, I am beginner, in php.

Comment: header('Location: '. "URL/".$_GET["sixdigit"] . ".html");

Comment: Basically the "header" function needs a string: header('Location: www.google.de'); And you just concat an additianal string (in PHP with a "." )

Comment: Yeah, I didn't add the . to add string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned redirect. Are you referring to a search-like box that will redirect to another .html page?

If so, you can redirect this way in your .php page.

```
header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
```

Depending where you want to redirect specifically, you could try

> header("Location: ../123456.html");
>   I would like to ask, what kind of application is are working on?